# Ember Dynamic Segment Unavailable in Route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following router setup in Ember where I am trying to capture a dynamic search term and pass it to the router for querying ember-data.

**Router**

```
this.resource('resources', function() {
  this.resource('resource', { path: '/:resource_id' }, function() {});
  this.resource('search', { path: '/search/:search_term' }, function() {});
  this.route('new');
});
```

**Route**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.findQuery('resource', {
      sTerm: params.search_term,
      limit: 15,
      offset: 0      
    });
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, search_term in not available in the route to pass into the query, I am unsure what is causing this not to work.  If someone can point me in the right direction I would sure appreciate it.  Thanks.

**Update as requested**

Logging this.constructor produces the following:

lrs-ui@route:search/index:

I have built this with ember-cli and the route is in search/index so this makes sense.  Should I just have the route at search maybe?

**Answer**

As @kingpin2k led to, the route was in search/index and it needed to be in search, then everything worked just fine.

Comment: I'm assuming this is the search route, what's the url when you visit the route, what's in param when it hits the model hook?

Comment: Yes, this is the search route, the url I am visiting is: `/resources/search/cc-17-14` I just need the last piece `cc-17-14` to be passed to the route so I can use it in the store query, and nothing is there in the params variable in the route when I go to this address.

Comment: honestly, the only thing that I can think, is it isn't the search route, it's the search index route, or something like that...

Comment: Will you add this to the model hook, and update the question with what it outputs: `console.log(this.constructor)`

Comment: @kingpin2k You figured it out, the route was originally at search/index and it wasn't picking up the param.  Moving the route to just search solved the problem.  Thank you.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad to hear it's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For historical sake, the index route doesn't pick up the params from the parent resource.

Changing the route from search/index to search fixed the issue.